# Receiving 403 from /webConfig

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-remote-config

I'm using firebase with firestore... and receiving this error from `/webConfig`.

I do not call this endpoint.. this was called by firebase... maybe because the remote config.

And yes.. I already enabled the API `Firebase Remote Config API`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that this is a missing permissions error, so could you share how your firebase rules are set? Also, have you added the api key to the header of the request in order to authenticate?

Comment: Which permissions are missing?

Comment: Can't say with what you shared so far, could you share your firebase rules? It's likely that the issue is there, and also could you confirm if you have added the api key to the header of the request in order to authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your API key has access for **Firebase Management API**, if not, allow it.

[image: Screenshot explaining firebase management api in google developer console]